# Why isn't html audio autoplay working

Tags: javascript, html

Is this bugged or something? please help me. I am coding a website but it doesn't work. I use Google chrome. Is there a compatibility issue?

```html
<audio autoplay id="myaudio" allow="autoplay">
<source src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Fuse Burning-SoundBible.com-1372982430.mp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script> document.getElementById('myaudio').play(); </script>
```

Comment: `http://soundbible.com/mp3/Fuse Burning-SoundBible.com-1372982430.mp3.mp3` doesn’t exist. Remove one of the `.mp3`, then it’ll work.

Answer (score 2):

looks like your URL in the  isn't working. Remove one .mp3 and it should work for you.

```html
<audio autoplay id="myaudio" allow="autoplay">
<source src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Fuse Burning-SoundBible.com-1372982430.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script> document.getElementById('myaudio').play(); </script>
```

Comment: Do you want to add a corrected version of OP's snippet to your answer? Might be useful because of the before / after effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the console when on you browser where your your snippet is running you will be able to see the following error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

404 error indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

In your case the server couldn't find the specified mp3 file. Looking at the code you have and extra .mp3 in your url so removing that will fix your issue.

```html
<audio autoplay id="myaudio" allow="autoplay">
<source src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Fuse Burning-SoundBible.com-1372982430.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script> document.getElementById('myaudio').play(); </script>
```