# Why won't the autoplay attribute work in HTML5?

Tags: html, css

```
<audio loop autoplay>
<source src="background-music.mp3">
</audio>
```

```
audio {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

I am using the above code and no music plays when I open the page. I expected it to autoplay and loop but it doesn't do anything. No errors in console, no nothing. I've searched the web, used the src attribute in the audio tag, but no change in what happens. Just saying I used repl.it and Notepad++.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `mute` attribute?

Comment: Modern browsers do not normally allow autoplay of media content unless the media is muted (which for audio defeats its entire purpose). Playback has to be initiated by some form of user interaction.

Comment: @EGC Never tried using `mute`

Comment: @Lennholm So could I just have a button that says "unmute music" and have the user click it to play the music?

Comment: So.. add the `mute` attribute and let me know if autoplay works?

Comment: @EGC I tried adding mute but it still doesn't do anything?

Comment: Kinda hard to tell if a hidden and muted audio element is playing or not ;)

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46528203/11700321

Comment: Or via script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041202/11700321

Comment: for that The browser supported by HTML audio autoplay attribute are listed below: `Google Chrome 4.0` `Internet Explorer 9.0` `Firefox 3.5` `Safari 4.0` `Opera 10.5`